# RecordRTC posting video blog with PHP fail

Tags: php

more specifically this https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP which muaz has done.

Basically it is only working for very short recordings less than a second. In the net console in FireFox I'm getting "POST save.php aborted". I've not really changed any of the code yet so all I can think is that it's because it's currently hosted on a shared server? It will be on a dedicated server eventually but I'm hoping it's an issue that is fixable before that time. Any ideas?

```
<?php
// Muaz Khan     - www.MuazKhan.com 
// MIT License   - https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/licence/
/RecordRTC
foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

    echo 'uploads/';

    $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
    $uploadDirectory = 'uploads/'.$fileName;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
        echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
    }

    echo($fileName);
}
```

}
?>

EDIT: So this issue seems to only be happening on one windows computer. I've tried it on a separate mac and it works fine. I will be trying on a another windows as soon as possible. Could it be due to the lesser performance of this computer?

Comment: "Hi I'm using recordRTC, more specifically this https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP which muaz has done." is the first line. Not sure why that all didn't post

Comment: my guess is some issue in save.php but without code it's hard to tell

Comment: @RamRaider sorry, i've edited with the save file code

Edit: Also the github link has all the code i'm using. I've only changed the $uploadDirectory and I removed this line (which is in the index.html):

   window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if (!!fileName) {
                deleteAudioVideoFiles();
                return 'It seems that you\'ve not deleted audio/video files from the server.';
            }
        };

Answer (score 0):

You missed checking this wiki page:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/wiki/PHP-Upload-Issues

> This wiki page explains how to modify php.ini file or .htaccess file to support large-size uploads in PHP applications. Such issues usually happens when you try to record 2-3 minutes of audio/video streams and resulting Blobs size gets bigger/larger than 6MB.

It proposes `.htaccess` and `php.ini` solutions. You can even set such globals directly in your PHP codes however such codes rarely works:

## .htaccess solution

`<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
php_value max_input_time 10800
php_value max_execution_time 10800
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
</IfModule>`

Don't forget checking PHP-info to make sure above changes really happened. Simply create a new php page `test.php` and paste following code:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: ahh I did try the .htaccess but I didn't check to see if the changes had happened. I'm rather new to this! Thanks muaz very kind of you to share your knowledge

Comment: due to it being on a shared server I can't access the php.ini but was able to set the session.gc_maxlifetime and max_execution_time to 10800, just not the rest. max_input_time is 60, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size is 64m. 

I have just noticed that on the demo it is now failing to upload more than a second or so. Is this likely to be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I have tested on another computer and found it is this computer that is the issue. Going to try clearing the cache